# how to get all store name with there categories?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working on custom module in which i m using a admin panel form where i want to display all store with their category .

```
<?php

class Matrid_Feedmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Web_Edit_Tab_Categoryform extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
 protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
      $this->setForm($form);
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('category_filter_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('web')->__('Category Filter Type')));  




$fieldset->addField('includecheckboxes', 'checkboxes', array(

'label' => Mage::helper('web')->__(''),
'name' => 'Checkbox',
'values' => array( array('value'=>'1','label'=>'<b> Include </b>all products from the selected categories')),'onclick' => "",'onchange' => "",'value' => '1',
'disabled' => false,

'tabindex' => 1

));

$fieldset->addField('excludecheckboxes', 'checkboxes', array(

'label' => Mage::helper('web')->__(''),
'name' => 'Checkbox',
'values' => array( array('value'=>'1','label'=>'<b> Exclude </b>all products from the selected categories')),'onclick' => "",'onchange' => "",'value' => '1',
'disabled' => false,

'tabindex' => 1

));
     $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('category_mapping_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('web')->__('Category Selection and Mapping')));





      if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWebData() )
      {
          $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWebData());
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setWebData(null);
      } elseif ( Mage::registry('web_data') ) {
          $form->setValues(Mage::registry('web_data')->getData());
      }

      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
  protected function _prepareCollection()
{
 $store = $this->_getStore();
 $collection = Mage::getModel('web')->getCollection();
 $this->setCollection($collection);
 parent::_prepareCollection();
 return $this;
}
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('web')->__('storeid'),
            'index' => 'store_id',
            'type' => 'number',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('store_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('web')->__('store name'),
            'index' => 'name',
        ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}



}
```

Comment: You mean you want to display all categories as per store vise ?

Comment: yes  but its not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code :

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()); //categories from current store will be fetched;
foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category->getName();
}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: Can you please mention error?

Comment: page not loading crtical error in cms module i thnk this code is not working

Comment: I checked it. It's proper working. There are in other code something wrong.

Comment: can u send me it in proper way ??

Comment: process how to show store name in admin panel form